# How to register types by convention using Unity with Prism?

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-container, prism, prism-6

I have a WPF app that uses the `Prism.Wpf` and `Prism.Unity` NuGet packages (both `6.3.0`). I'm currently registering types in the Unity container manually in a bootstrapper class (see below) and everything is working great.

```
internal class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        base.ConfigureContainer();

        // Register types
        Container.RegisterType<IDialogService, DialogService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    }
}
```

However, when I try to register types by convention, I get a `Microsoft.Practices.Unity.DuplicateTypeMappingException` when registering the types in the Unity container.

The register by convention code:

```
protected override void ConfigureContainer()
{
    base.ConfigureContainer();

    // Register types by convention
    Container.RegisterTypes(
        AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(),
        WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
        WithName.Default,
        WithLifetime.ContainerControlled);
}
```

Exception message:

`An attempt to override an existing mapping was detected for type Prism.Regions.IRegionNavigationContentLoader with name "", currently mapped to type Prism.Unity.Regions.UnityRegionNavigationContentLoader, to type Prism.Regions.RegionNavigationContentLoader.`

**How do I register types by convention when using Prism & Unity?**

Comment: @downvoter - how can I improve the question? Downvoting without a comment doesn't help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just swap `Container.RegisterTypes(...);` and `base.ConfigureContainer();`

The `UnityBootstrapper` will only register types that weren't registered before, so you should be fine.